# Can you share the session variables between two .net 2.0+ applications?

Tags: asp.net, session

I was told this works, but...

I guess I'm just not getting this, it seems there's a hidden step I may be missing, can anyone correct this or point out my mistake? Thanks.

I have a blank solution:
- inside is two .net 2.0 web applications
1) webapp1
2) webapp2

I want them to share the same session data.

My page setups:

Application 1:

```
Session("value") = "this is the value"
```

Application 2:

```
If Not (Session("value") Is Nothing) Then
    value = Session("value").ToString()
End If
```

My thought process:

1) go to services, turn on the asp.net state service
2) open the web configs in both projects: set the

```
< machineKey 
validationKey="BFE2909A81903BB303D738555FEBC0C63EB39636F6FEFBF8005936CBF5FEB88CE327BDBD56AD70749F502FF9D5DECF575C13FA2D17CA8870ED21AD935635D4CC" 
decryptionKey="2A86BF77049EBA3A2FA786325592D640D5ACD17AF8FFAC04" validation="SHA1" />
< sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=localhost:42424" 
cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>
```

in both sites.
3) compile and test the site
4) become disappointed because it does not work. I never see the session from the second webapp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to share Sessions between applications? ASP.NET Session is not designed to do that.

Your proposed solution of using the same ASP.NET State Server does not work because your user will simply get 2 different session tokens, even if they use your 2 applications concurrently from the same machine, and same browser. You need to consider how Session works to understand why this is.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx):

> ASP.NET session state enables you to store and retrieve values for a
>   user as the user navigates ASP.NET pages in a Web application. HTTP is
>   a stateless protocol. This means that a Web server treats each HTTP
>   request for a page as an independent request. The server retains no
>   knowledge of variable values that were used during previous requests.
>   ASP.NET session state identifies requests from the same browser during
>   a limited time window as a session, and provides a way to persist
>   variable values for the duration of that session.

ASP.NET Session is a metaphor for a user's current interaction with **one ASP.NET application**. It exists in ASP.NET to give us a place to store temporary state data between the various page requests that a user makes while using your application.

If your applications are very closely related, e.g. the user uses both at the same time, or almost the same time, you could consider merging them into a single ASP.NET application. You could deploy them into different Virtual Directories to maintain some degree of logical separation, but use only one Application in IIS.

If your applications are not that closely related, perhaps they should be sharing the same database as a means to exchange data, or using an API e.g. based on Web Services to exchange information.

Comment: This is not an answer. "Why would you want to do that" == "I don't know how to do that". Some people may have sites that are cannot be merged for any number of other reasons (corporate decisions or whatever). If there is a way to do this it should be explored, not simply ignored.

Comment: @mikeschuld The Session metaphor applies to a users current interactions with a single ASP.NET application and is not appropriate outside that use case. Once you look outside the Session metaphor you will find there are plenty of other ways to share data, and a far better solution would be to explore other options. I've hinted at merging the apps, or sharing same DB, or interfacing between apps, because I believe that is a far better solution that hacking Session to do things it is not designed to do.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot share sessions between different ASP.NET applications without some custom code. What you did in web.config was to use an out of process sessions, which means that data will no longer reside into memory but into the memory of a dedicated machine. This is useful for server farms and it uses the ApplicationName to know which application the session belongs to. So basically your applications need to have the same name if you want them to share sessions. There are some dirty [workarounds](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/session/sharedsession.aspx) though.

Comment: that work around did not work for me, and it looks like it did not work for almost anyone there as well... how do you set the application name? i cannot use an sql server, i need to use state server, or in process..

Comment: In my personal experience, I never had to share session state between two different ASP.NET applications so I cannot guarantee. The solution on CodeProject seems hacky but IMHO it should work.

Answer (score 1):

They will share session data if they are in the same app pool and the session mode is set to inproc. The way that stateserver and sqlstate work is they use the root of your web address as logical boundaries.

Eg if they are both hosted on the same address and port (or 'site' in iis) but in different sibfolders then they should share session I think.

Comment: that will work because the projects would be compiled as one project, yes, however we dont want that, we want to compile both projects separate, and then deploy them side by side - different virtual directories.

Comment: I tried the same , Still not working this way either

Answer (score 1):

Additionally both apps must run on the same domain so that user browser use one cookie to store session id.

Comment: I tried the same , Still not working this way either