# Same Session variable names in different web applications hosted on same server/app pool

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, configuration, session-variables, session-timeout

We have two different web applications hosted on same box belonging to same application pool.

We have used lot of session variables in both of these web applications using inproc. Most of these session variables have same name.

Lets say App 1 has variable called Session["Name"], it gets genuinely cleared due to code some logic.

Will it also clear the value of session variable value with same name in App 2 as well ?

We are seeing users being thrown out to login page all of sudden in middle of page operations.

Does Session.Abandon() or Session.System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.RemoveAll() will throw users out in such fashion ?

We have app recycle set to specific time interval i.e. at night.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623551/can-you-share-the-session-variables-between-two-net-2-0-applications),

> They will share session data if they are in the same app pool and the session mode is set to inproc.